# Laravel Sail User and Groups in exist project

Tags: laravel, docker, laravel-sail

I want to install laravel sail in an existing project using the command from the documentation

```
docker run --rm \
    -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
    -v $(pwd):/var/www/html \
    -w /var/www/html \
    composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

but after launching the sail up, my directories are rooted

how can i change it to "sail" with group 1000?

thx!

Comment: you should use the following command, only using the laravelsail/phpXX-composer image

```
docker run --rm \
    -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
    -v $(pwd):/var/www/html \
    -w /var/www/html \
    laravelsail/php81-composer:latest \
    composer install --ignore-platform-reqs

```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this issue on laravel sail repo on GitHub solve your problem
https://github.com/laravel/sail/issues/81

Comment: Please also quote snippet which will help solve OPs problem as links can be dead any time, for future SO readers.